# Preventing access to a jspx page from browser

Tags: jsf, web.xml, oracle-adf

I created a test.jspx file under WEB-INF and I am trying to access it via a servlet by a request dispatcher, but I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext`.

The `web.xml` mapping is as follows:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

It works fine if I use `.jsp`.

My request dispacther code is as follow:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jspx?sessid="+id);
dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Answer (score 1):

The request URL (which you see in browser address bar) or the forward URL (which you used in `RequestDispatcher#forward()`) **must** match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` in order to get it to run and process all JSF components in the JSF page.

You've mapped the `FacesServlet` on an URL pattern of `/faces/*` and you're trying to invoke it from some homebrewed servlet (why?), so the forward URL must match that URL pattern. Put the page outside `/WEB-INF` and forward to `/faces/test.jspx` instead.